# Subclassing swift generic decodable type

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

**EDIT:** As [Rob Napier wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540809/9565342), the problem exists in Xcode 9.2. In Xcode 9.3 the issue is no longer relevant.

My server json responses are all packed inside `data` object:

```
{ 
    "data": {...}
}
```

So I have the following generic type to parse JSON:

```
class DataContainer<T: Decodable>: Decodable {

    let data: T

    init(data: T)
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Most of the time it works fine, but there is one response in which I also need to parse `included` field so I have created `SpecificDataContainer` subclass:

```
class SpecificDataContainer: DataContainer<DataObject> {
    let included: [IncludedObject]

    init() {
        included = []
        super.init(data: DataObject(id: ""))
    }
}
```

Implementation above gives me compiler error `'required' initializer 'init(from:)' must be provided by subclass of 'DataContainer'`.

I implemented `init(from:)` in the `SpecificDataContainer` but compiler still gives me the same error.

It seems I miss something obvious here. What am I doing wrong? Here is my full code:

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
{
    "data": {
        "id": "some_id"
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "id": "some_id2"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using:.utf8)!

struct DataObject: Decodable {
    let id: String
}

struct IncludedObject: Decodable {
    let id: String
}

class DataContainer<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: T

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class SpecificDataContainer: DataContainer<DataObject> {
    let included: [IncludedObject]

    init() {
        included = []
        super.init(data: DataObject(id: ""))
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var includedArray = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .included)

        var includedObjects:[IncludedObject] = []
        while !includedArray.isAtEnd {
            let includedObject = try includedArray.decode(IncludedObject.self)
            includedObjects.append(includedObject)
        }
        self.included = includedObjects

        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case included = "included"
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
if let obj = try? decoder.decode(SpecificDataContainer.self, from: jsonData) {
    print("object id \(obj.data.id)")
} else {
    print("Fail!")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode 9.2. In 9.3b4 your code is fine.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason Xcode doesn't recognise the auto-generated `init(from:)` in subclasses of `Codable` (as Rob said it might be a bug). Until Xcode 9.3 is out you can work around this issue by adding the initializer to the base class also:

```swift
class DataContainer<T: Decodable>: Decodable {    
    let data: T

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data)
    }
```